# Result of SSIS Merge Join

Tags: sql-server, excel, merge, ssis, etl

I have two data sources - Document and Customer and I want to  join them, creating rows that that information both from documents and customer, having the customer_code as key.

Finally, I get only 58 out of 30k results that I expected.

Where is the flaw?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the customer_code column

Comment: As shown from Excel, there are both "General"
Switched to "Text", same results

Comment: customer_code contains numbers or characters or both?

Comment: the first thing you can do is to add a sort component before `Merge Join`. read my answer to get more informations

Comment: i am still waiting for your reply !!

Answer (score 0):

**Many things to take into consideration:**

1. When importing excel files with **mixed data types column** it will replace non dominant types by null. (Using Oledb or Ace.Oledb)

In case that the Customer_code column contains multiple data type (ex: Numbers, Number stored as text) so the non dominant data type fields will be set to `null`. So you have that all values in a column are stored with the same data type in excel *(you have to open excel to check that)*

You can read more @ [Importing data from Excel having Mixed Data Types in a column (SSIS)](https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/importing-data-from-excel-having-mixed-data-types-in-a-column-ssis/)

2. In case customer_No contains characters, you have to make sure that values from the two excel files have the same case **(join in ssis is case sensitive)**, or you have to add two derived column transformation to transform both `Customer_Code` columns to upper case using the following expression:

   ```
   UPPER([Customer_Code])
   ```
3. According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/sort-data-for-the-merge-and-merge-join-transformations), *"In Integration Services, the Merge and Merge Join transformations require sorted data for their inputs. The input data must be sorted physically, and sort options must be set on the outputs and the output columns in the source or in the upstream transformation. If the sort options indicate that the data is sorted, but the data is not actually sorted, the results of the merge or merge join operation are unpredictable"*

So try adding sort component on each source before merge join